# ansible - get host by variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I would like to filter hosts by a variable set on them. For example:

I have a group of hosts, one is master, the rest are slaves. On the master the variable `replica_type: master` is set. I would now like to get the master server dynamically.

My working aproach is:

```
- set_fact:
    master_server_string: >-
      {% for server in groups.my_servers %}
      {% if hostvars[server]['replica_type']=='master' -%}
      {{ server }}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
- set_fact:
    master_server: "{{ master_server_string|trim }}"
```

Is there a way to perform the same with a filter (or at least in a single task)?
e.g. something like

```
"{{ server for server in groups.my_servers if hostvars[server]['replica_type'] == 'master' }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the `group_by` module.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/group_by_module.html

```
- group_by:
    key: {{ replica_type }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pull a value out of a group of hosts by a property by looping the group and checking for a matching value like this too:

```
- set_fact:
    master_server: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ groups.my_servers }}"
  when: hostvars[item].replica_type == 'master'
```

Comment: This solution is as good as the accepted one, just another possibility